# Is t possible/feasible to use android's NDK toolchain to cross-compile for Pi?

Tags: c, android, cross-compilation, clang

That's it, really. I have an x86_64 host that already cross-compiles a C application for android's 4 supported architectures, could I use the existing toolchain to build armeabi-v7a for a Pi (running Linux like Raspbian or whatever)?

**Edit 1**

I extracted the ext4 filesystem from [Raspberry OS](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_armhf/images/raspios_lite_armhf-2021-05-28/2021-05-07-raspios-buster-armhf-lite.zip) and monted it onto `/opt/rpi/sysroot.img`.

I then tried

```
~/Android/Sdk/ndk/22.0.7026061/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang \
-target arm-v7a-none-linux-eabi \
-mfloat-abi=hard \
-nostdinc \
-std=c99 \
-isysroot /opt/rpi/sysroot.img \
-c helloRaspi.c
```

but hit a sort of lib hell. The compiler complains it can't find `stdio.h`, then `stddef.h`, etc.

I was under the assumption `-isysroot` would change the root for the compiler search paths, but i noticed that's not quite what it does, as providing e.g. `-I/opt/rpi/sysroot.img/usr/include/c++/8/tr1` will find `stdarg.h` but `-I/usr/include/c++/8/tr1` won't. And what's the difference to `--sysroot`?

My current compilation line is at

```
~/Android/Sdk/ndk/22.0.7026061/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang 
-target arm-v7a-none-linux-eabi 
-mfloat-abi=hard 
-nostdinc 
-std=c99 
-isysroot /opt/rpi/sysroot.img 
-I/opt/rpi/sysroot.img/usr/include                          stdio.h
-I/opt/rpi/sysroot.img/usr/include/linux                    stddef.h
-I/opt/rpi/sysroot.img/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf      bits/libc-header-start.h
-I/opt/rpi/sysroot.img/usr/include/c++/8                    tr1/cstdarg
-I/opt/rpi/sysroot.img/usr/include/c++/8/tr1                stdarg.h
-I/opt/rpi/sysroot.img/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/c++/8  bits/c++config.h
-c helloRaspi.c
```

(the file names were added of course), but now am getting errors in the included files themselves, such as

```
In file included from /opt/rpi/sysroot.img/usr/include/stdio.h:43:
/opt/rpi/sysroot.img/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/types/struct_FILE.h:95:3: error: unknown type name 'size_t'
  size_t __pad5;
```

which makes me think i got the include path all wrong from the start.

For completeness this is my helloWorld:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't grok `-isysroot` and `--sysroot`, maybe clang handles them differently than [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html) (it's not exactly [verbose](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html) regarding those two options), but I got it to compile as such:

```
export CLANG=/home/user/Android/Sdk/ndk/22.0.7026061/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang
export SROOT=/opt/rpi/sysroot.img
${CLANG} -v -target arm-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi -mfloat-abi=hard -std=c99 \
-nostdinc \
-I${SROOT}/usr/include \
-I${SROOT}/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf \
-I${SROOT}/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/include \
helloRaspi.c -o helloRaspi
```

Ran successfully on a Raspberry Pi 4 B.~

...whether this is feasible for a larger program remains to be seen.